# jQuery form plugin redirecting

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using the jQuery form plugin from http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

On my test page it works perfectly, but for some on my final page with a bunch of dynamically generated items,  the form is submitting to my ajax php and then redirecting me there like a traditional html form would.

Here's the html for each form:

```
 <form class="comform" action="ajax/comment.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<? echo $id;?>">
  <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="2" class="commenttext" id="amazing"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="+" /> 
</form>
```

and the script being used:

```
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('.comform').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("working, change this later"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

As I said this is submitting via ajax to comment.php, but on the real page with multiple comment boxes it is also redirecting to ajax/comment.php

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you need to `return false` in the callback in order to prevent the browser's default action.

See the plugin's API documentation [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api).

Note that `ajaxSubmit` requires `return false`.  Granted, this is only when you manually call the submit function, but it may indicate that the plugin doesn't prevent the event propagation by default.